# How to develop a real time system using PHP & MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, architecture, real-time

I will be working on a project for my friend. It will involve handling real time user data. Like SO, I would like to let a user login with his/her OpenID. I want advice on

- MySQL db engine and or design for a real time system
- authentication mechanisms
- I am good at CodeIgniter and chances are I will be using it, any other suggestion
- jQuery has most supporter/users here on SO and I am comfortable with jQuery as well as Prototype, out of these two which one is better or there is any other competitor to these?

The system will have users, who will be using a stand-alone client that will communicate with centralised server, one can have a view of this data on web front end.

Comment: Please define "real time" in more detail - the term has [multiple meanings in IT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_computing)

Comment: The term "real-time system" usually refers to something in the industrial or mechanical control domain, where hardware/software has to respond to events with very tight time constraints.

Comment: One tip to share with you would be that you should ask targeted relevant questions rather than vague, overly broad ones.

Comment: For any new development, I'd recommend Postgres over MySQL. Especially if you'll be running lots of complex queries. (The kind ORMs love to generate)

Comment: @all: consider real time data to be equivalent of tweets, though it has nothing to do with twitter.

Comment: @Kumar, you mean asynchronous? Ajax calls?

Comment: @Kumar you should probably explain in more detail what you are planning to do

Comment: @Pekka, I have added details, yes ajax will be involved, obvious

Comment: @Kumar so you are looking to implement something like a chat?

Comment: @Pekka, nothing like chat, not even remotely similar to chat or tweeting or facebook. consider it as a web front end for a p2p client

Comment: @Kumar a p2p server in PHP? O_o ... PHP may not be the best technology for that. Sorry, this is really too broad to be answered meaningfully without more info

Comment: @Pekka what would you suggest then? Python?

Comment: I have voted to close this as Needs Focus, as it was far too broad to be answerable when it was asked, and the question requirements are even tighter now.

Answer (score 0):

Similar Question : [Is there a way to have PHP print the data to a web browser in real time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133935/is-there-a-way-to-have-php-print-the-data-to-a-web-browser-in-real-time)

Javascript library is your choice.

For real time web applications trends like [WebSocket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSockets), [Server-Sent Events](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-sent_events) are not supported across all platforms.
You might consider checking [Push Technology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology), [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming)). Hope this gives you some direction.